# is it possible to access variables in other screens/functions in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm just curious whether you can access variables to other functions or screens? Because in my app, I have screens for adding balance and withdraws and I have to get the values I have in add balance so whenever the user gets withdraw, the current balance will be deducted from the balance they currently have vice versa. So let say I have an inner function in add balance like this:

```
function addTogether(){
const Total = balance + amount;
newBalance(Total);
MyFunction();
```

and what I want to do is to get the variable Total or get access from the withdraw screens so I can deduct the current balance from the amount the user has added. How can I call that in state from withdraw components?

Comment: What you're looking for is called 'state management'.  There are tons of ways to do this, some built-in to React, others externally.  If you do a search for "state managment in react" you'll get to see some solutions and weigh pros and cons.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)